# Unchecked_Conversion in Ada

Tags: ada, unchecked-conversion

Can anyone please make me clear about the use of unchecked conversion in the Ada language.I had tried the pdf and net but all doesn't give me a clear picture to me.

Now I have a small piece of code shown below:

```
subtype Element4_Range is integer range 1..4;
subtype Element3_Range is integer range 1..3;
subtype Myarr_Range is integer range 1..10;
type Myarr3_Type is array (Myarr_Range) of Element3_Range;
type Myarr4_Type is array (Myarr_Range) of Element4_Range;
Myarr3 : Myarr3_Type;
Myarr4 : Myarr4_Type := (1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1);
Count_1 : Integer := 0;
Count_2 : Integer := 0;
Count_3 : Integer := 0;
*function To_Myarr3 is new Unchecked_Conversion(Myarr4_type, Myarr3_type);*
```

Now my doubt here is what does the function Myarr3 exactly do?

Answer (score 3):

An instantiation of `Unchecked_Conversion` copies the bytes of the source value to the target without checking whether this is sensible. Some compilers will warn (depending maybe on compilation options) if the values are of different sizes.

`Element3_Range` and `Element4_Range` are both based on `Integer` and will use the same number of bytes; so both of your array variables (`Myarr3`, `Myarr4`) will need the same number of bytes (40 typically).

You could write

```
Myarr3 := To_Myarr3 (Myarr4);
```

As it stands, nothing bad would happen because all the values you've used to initialise `Myarr4` are legal as values of `Element3_Range`.

However, if you had

```
Myarr3 := To_Myarr3 (Myarr4'(1, 2, 3, 4, others => 1));
```

you'd end up with `Myarr3(4)` containing a value outside the legal range of `Element3_Range`, and with the compiler having no reason to believe that it might not be valid. This may well lead to `Constraint_Error`s down the line.

You could force a check yourself:

```
if not Myarr3 (4)'Valid then
  -- handle the error case
```

Answer (score 2):

I had an coworker once who instisted that `unchecked_conversion` should have been named "Unchcked_Copy" instead. All it does is copy an object of one type into an object of another type.

So your `To_Myarr3` routine will accept as a parameter an array of type Myarr4, pretend it is an array of type Myarr3, and then copy every element in it into the left-hand side of your expression.

If you want to change your view of an object from one type to another without copying the whole darn thing around, you can instead use an Unchecked_Conversion on access types for them (so you are only copying the pointer to them). Another method is using `for object_name'address use at` to overlay one on the other (however, they may both get initialized, which can be bad). But really the best way is to **design your system's types so that you never have to use Unchecked_Conversion**.